# Shopify: How do shopify apps place an iframe on thank you page?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I've tried searching everywhere and looking at all the docs. There's nothing that shows how apps place an iframe inside the thank you page after the checkout.
How do other apps do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order status page is known as Thank you page in Shopify. From [Shopify Docs](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/orders/status-tracking/customize-order-status)

> Different fields appear on the order status page depending on whether
> the status is confirmed, on its way, out for delivery, or delivered.

Generally, Shopify Apps add [Script Tag](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/online-store/scripttag) via API to include their JavaScript on Shopify Store. The ***display_scope*** property can be **order_status** or **all** so that custom JavaScript also loads on Thank you page.

```
POST /admin/api/2020-07/script_tags.json
{
  "script_tag": {
    "event": "onload",
    "src": "https://djavaskripped.org/fancy.js",
    "display_scope": "order_status"
  }
}
```

Once the JavaScript is loaded, the app may add iframe or anything that is needed. To extend the Order status page, Shopify also provides a JavaScript function named **[addContentBox](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/orders/status-tracking/customize-order-status/order-status-javascript-asset)**.

```
Shopify.Checkout.OrderStatus.addContentBox(
  "<h2>Pick-up in store</h2>",
  "<p>We are open everyday from 9am to 5pm.</p>"
);
```